# Como fazer a colisão do meu player com um tile na Unity 5?

Tags: unity-5, detecção-de-colisão

Preciso colocar colisões em alguns tiles estáticos para que o player não possa passar por eles. Tentei colocar um `Box Collider 2D` no player e no tile mas não está funcionando. Como resolvo isso da melhor maneira possível, de maneira que melhore a performance da Unity. (Vão existir **muitos** colliders)

Obs: Não quero scripts para isso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente colocar o Box Collider apenas no tile, e no player vc usa um Rigidbody 2d, isso deve funcionar.

Comment: @JúlioNeto Não funcionou!

Answer (score 1):

Para que haja colisão no seu caso, você deve atribuir um Collider no Tile e no player adicionar um RigiBody e também um Collider. Ressaltando que ambos os componentes devem ser do tipo 2D, do contrário não funcionará. Vale lembrar que você deve se atentar a que tamanho está o Collider, pois talvez não esteja circundando o objeto de forma correta.